# How to get started with Kinect Development

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect

I'm new to Kinect Development
I've installed VS2010, Kinect SDK & .NET4

I want to know how to get image frames from the Kinect sensor in C++. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Is there no documentation or samples for that SDK?

Comment: Why not read the documentation and work yourself through the examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

[Here's an updated version for Kinect V2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Programming-Kinect-for-Windows-v2) from July 2014.

---

Check out this serie on channel9 : http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts